# Concatenate rows of pandas DataFrame with same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas DataFrame such as:

```
   A  B  id
0  1  1   0
1  2  1   0
2  3  2   1
3  0  2   1
```

Say I want to combine rows with the same id so that the other elements in the rows get put together in a list, so that the above dataframe would become:

```
     A       B     id
0  [1, 2]  [1, 1]   0
1  [3, 0]  [2, 2]   1
```

as the first two rows, and the last two rows have the same id. Does pandas have a function to do this? I am aware of the pandas groupby command, but I would like the return type to be a dataframe as well. Thanks.

Comment: I am aware of the pandas groupby command, but I would like the return type to be a dataframe as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for that with groupby `agg` method and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method of Pandas Series:

```
In [762]: df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[762]: 
         A       B
id                
0   [1, 2]  [1, 1]
1   [3, 0]  [2, 2]
```

`groupby` return an Dataframe as you want:

```
In [763]: df1 = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

In [764]: type(df1)
Out[764]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

To exactly match your expected result you could additionally do `reset_index` or use `as_index=False` in `groupby`:

```
In [768]: df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[768]: 
   id       A       B
0   0  [1, 2]  [1, 1]
1   1  [3, 0]  [2, 2]

In [771]: df1.reset_index()
Out[771]: 
   id       A       B
0   0  [1, 2]  [1, 1]
1   1  [3, 0]  [2, 2]
```