# Pandas: Group two columns based on value in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm pretty new to python/pandas and I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
 id         name        color
id_1        alex        blue
id_2        james       yellow
id_1        sara        black
id_4        dave        pink
id_4        lin         grey
id_2        aly         red
```

I want to group by id and get the values in the other two columns as a list:

```
  id           name              color
id_1        [alex,sara]       [blue,black]
id_2        [james,aly]       [yellow,red]
id_4        [dave,lin]        [pink,grey]
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776651/concatenate-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-with-same-id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by custom function with `tolist`:

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
print (df)
              name          color
id                               
id_1  [alex, sara]  [blue, black]
id_2  [james, aly]  [yellow, red]
id_4   [dave, lin]   [pink, grey]
```